# How to output unique tuples from a list of lists?

Tags: python

```
data = [
    [(1, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (1, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])],
    [(2, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (2, 2, 0, ['PESOCHEK'])],
    [(3, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (3, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])]
]
```

**I need to output a list of points based on this logic:**

in the list data[0] there is a point (1, 1, 0, ['EARTH']) - write it to the result.

there is a point in the list data[0] (1, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK']) - write it to the result.

in the list data[1] there is also a point (2, 1, 0, ['EARTH']) - with the same description as in the previous list, which means we do not write it to the result.

in the list data[1] there is a point (2, 2, 0, ['PESOCHEK']) - write it to the result.

in the data[2] list there is a point (3, 1, 0, ['EARTH']) - with the same description as in the previous list, which means we do not write it to the result.

in the list data[2] there is a point (3, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK']) - we write it to the result, because there is no such thing in the previous list

The result should look like this:

`result = [(1, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (1, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), (2, 2, 0, ['PESOCHEK']), (3, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])]`

I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
data = [
    [(1, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (1, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])],
    [(2, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (2, 2, 0, ['PESOCHEK'])],
    [(3, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (3, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])]
]

result = []

for sublist in data:
    for point in sublist:
        found = False
        for existing_point in result:
            if point[:3] == existing_point[:3] and point[3][0] == existing_point[3][0]:
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            result.append(point)

print(result)
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you require that `point[:3] == existing_point[:3]`? In your example this comparison will never be true... If you'd use a debugger, you'd detected this yourself.

Comment: I don't know why `(2, 1, 0, ['EARTH'])` can't append while `(3, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])` can append. I think there is a typo in OP. pls check and fix it, it is not clear now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: @EdwardZotov, Please see my second answer. I've answered once again towards your present query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a set of every description you've seen in the previous list on each iteration, and only add points in the current list that don't have descriptions in the set of previous descriptions

```py
iterator = iter(data)
prev = next(iterator, [])

result = list(prev)
for row in iterator:
    # In this approach, the description is assumed to always be a single element
    previous_desc = {point[-1][0] for point in prev}
    # In this approach, the description is a sequence of elements, where order matters
    #previous_desc = {tuple(point[-1]) for point in prev}
    # In this approach, the description is a collection of unique elements where order doesn't matter
    #previous_desc = {frozenset(point[-1]) for point in prev}

    for point in row:
        if tuple(point[-1]) not in previous_desc:
            result.append(point)
    prev = row
```

Note, the above returns an empty list when you pass it an empty list.

Also note, when I create the set of description strings, I assume there is always a single string, because that is what the examples in your question imply.

I've added two different approaches for how to handle that list as a basis for comparison. You can use a `tuple` if there are non-unique elements where order matters, or you can use a `frozenset` if only the unique elementer matter, and their order doesn't.

There are other possibilities for how to treat the list of strings as a basis for comparison.

Comment: data = [ [ (1011, 944, 0, ['EARTH']), (1011, 940, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), (1011, 932, 0, ['PESOK']), ], [ (1022, 944, 0, ['EARTH']), (1022, 940, 0, ['PESOK']), ] ] If I insert this data, it will produce the following result: [(1011, 944, 0, ['EARTH']), (1011, 940, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), (1011, 932, 0, ['PESOK']), (1022, 940, 0, ['PESOK'])] PESOK should not be output a second time because there is already PESOK in the previous list. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @EdwardZotov that's unlike your original data, where the lengths were 2. Not sure I understand the logic

Comment: 'data' list can contain any number of tuples. And if, for example, there is a tuple with a similar description in data[0], then there is no need to output a tuple with the same description from data[1].

Comment: @EdwardZotov you are checking each element of the current list against all elements of the previous list? But you aren't comparing to all previous lists, correct?

Comment: For example, if data[0], data[1] and data[2] contain PESOK, then we output PESOK only from data[0].

If PESOK is in data[0] and data[2] then output PESOK twice - from data[0] and from data[2]

Comment: @EdwardZotov why is PESOK in your result twice? it is in data[0] and data[1] in the example you gave in the comment (you really should be editing your question and describing the logic in detail there)

Comment: in the comment I wrote the wrong result, which is what the code you sent gives me

Comment: @EdwardZotov ah I think I understand you...so it should return `[(1011, 944, 0, ['EARTH']),
 (1011, 940, 0, ['SUGLINOK']),
 (1011, 932, 0, ['PESOK'])]` ... see my edit

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. Read step by step you yourself will understand.

```
data = [
    [(1, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (1, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])],
    [(2, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (2, 2, 0, ['PESOCHEK'])],
    [(3, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (3, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])]
]

result = []

for i,x in enumerate(data):
    for j,y in enumerate(x):
        #for index is not 0 matching checked
        if i != 0:
            if x[j][3] != data[i-1][j][3]:
                result.append(x[j])
        #if index is 0, all the values are appended
        else:
            result.append(x[j])
print(result)
'''
output:
[(1, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (1, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), (2, 2, 0, ['PESOCHEK']), (3, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])]
'''
```

Comment: data = [
    [
        (1011, 944, 0, ['EARTH']), 
        (1011, 940, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), 
        (1011, 932, 0, ['PESOK']), 
    ], 
    [
        (1022, 944, 0, ['EARTH']), 
        (1022, 940, 0, ['PESOK']), 
    ]
]

If I insert this data, it will produce the following result:


[(1011, 944, 0, ['EARTH']), (1011, 940, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), (1011, 932, 0, ['PESOK']), (1022, 940, 0, ['PESOK'])]

PESOK should not be output a second time because there is already PESOK in the previous list.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: @EdwardZotov, Please see my second answer. I've answered once again towards your present query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) function to flatten the list of lists, and then use set to keep track of unique points.

```
from itertools import chain

data = [
    [(1, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (1, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])],
    [(2, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (2, 2, 0, ['PESOCHEK'])],
    [(3, 1, 0, ['EARTH']), (3, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK'])]
]


flattened_data = list(chain.from_iterable(data))
result_set = set(flattened_data)
result = list(result_set)

print(result)
```

output#

```
[(3, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), (2, 2, 0, ['PESOCHEK']), (1, 2, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), (1, 1, 0, ['EARTH'])]
```

Answer (score -1):

This answer is towards the question you asked in the comment session.As your question was not clear, I assumed the condition : if index-3 of the tuple if matches with the previous list's tuple with the same index.

After your comment, I came to know that the respective element should not be present in any of the tuple of the previous index. And here is the solution:

```
data = [ [ (1011, 944, 0, ['EARTH']), (1011, 940, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), (1011, 932, 0, ['PESOK']), ], 
        [ (1022, 944, 0, ['EARTH']), (1022, 940, 0, ['PESOK']), ] ] 

result = []
for i,x in enumerate(data):
    for j,y in enumerate(x):
        if i != 0:
            #create a list of 3rd element of previous list
            ref = [z[3] for z in data[i-1]]
            if y[3] not in ref: result.append(y)
        else: result.append(y)

print(result)
#output : [(1011, 944, 0, ['EARTH']), (1011, 940, 0, ['SUGLINOK']), (1011, 932, 0, ['PESOK'])]
```